# Pagination not working for all posts listing wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, posts

I am trying to fetch all posts in wordpress wp-admin ,pagination is not working
with wp_query function
only pagination links are shown at page , but all pages showing all posts / same posts

anyone having solution for this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this code :

```
<?php $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,        
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged,
);
  
$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
        $arr_posts->the_post();
        ?>

        <h3 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

        <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>


<div class="pagepagination">
<?php

$arr_posts_page = $arr_posts->max_num_pages;
if ($arr_posts_page > 1){

    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => 'page/%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $arr_posts_page,
        'prev_text'    => __('<'),
        'next_text'    => __('>'),
    ));
}
?>
</div>
```